# How can I solve "Gradle Project Sync Failed"?

Tags: java, android

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujEht.png)

I'm setting up a new Android project but when I create it it gives me this error **"Gradle project sync failed."**

The errors are as follows:

```
Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'nil.testapp' in default config.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1)

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
```

I checked that it wasn't running as "Offline Work".

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nil.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please also post your gradle configuration

Comment: error messages without the code that produces them do not exactly qualify as a question ...please add `build.gradle`; in particular the `repositories` and `dependencies` would be relevant.

Comment: okay ill add them

Comment: @JohnSnow and where is the library module, which causes the `Library projects cannot set applicationId.' in default config`... in this project should be 3 `build.gradle` present.

Comment: Did you add `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` on top of the app -build-file?

Comment: Run `./gradlew build --debug`, it will print a more detailed error message.

Comment: Now its giving me ```AAPT2 error: check logs for details``` 
with android issue ```error: resource string/app_name (aka nil.testapp:string/app_name) not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource string/app_name (aka nil.testapp:string/app_name) not found., ``` 
and Java Compiler issue ```error: failed processing manifest.```